# Нейтральний підпис в електронному листуванні

Tags: стилістика

Мене цікавить, які з варіантів закінчення електронного листа будуть доречними у неофіційному листуванні з людиною, з якою ви персонально не знайомі і не маєте жодної додаткової інформації про її вік чи соціальний статус (отже, жодних орієнтирів на рівень формальності).

Чи є добрими варіанти: "З повагою ...", "На все добре ..."? Чи є альтернативи?

Ресурси [Ділова українська мова](http://dilova.at.ua/publ/dilove_listuvannja/jak_treba_pochinati_i_zakinchuvati_dilovi_listi/3-1-0-86) та [Ділова мова](http://www.dilovamova.com/) або стосуються офіційного листування, або оминають цю тему.

Comment: Для суто ділових стосунків я вживаю "З повагою, " і важаю, що цього достатньо. "На все добре" або "Бажаю успіху" в залежності від контексту стосунків та поточного перебігу подій можуть бути трактовані інакше ніж Ви очикуєте.

Comment: Згоден. "З повагою" досить розповсюджений варіант і якійсь альтернативний я навіть не можу підібрати. Хібашо "Завжди ваш", але це вже менш нейтрально.  Також згадав "З найкращими побажаннями". Теж досить нейтральний варіант.

Comment: Свого часу мав доступ до офіційного листування одного з міністерств України, всілякі там запити і внутрішні листи між відомствами і відділами. Переважали такі закінчення: `З повагою`, `З глибокою пошаною`, `наперед дякую`.

Comment: @user1264176, "наперед дякую", так само як і "дякую за швидку відповідь" в перекладі з ділової мови означає "мені це конче треба, благаю, зроби це".

Comment: @Gluttton не заперечую. Просто даю статистику, тому і написав коментарем, а не відповіддю. Стосовно нейтральності - `З повагою`, як на мене, найкращий варіант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В нас досі не є усталений епістолярний стиль, бо те, що залишилося від СРСР виглядає архаїчно, а комусь і просто неприємно. (Той же "товариш" вже не працює, а щодо того, "шановний" чи "добродію" ще не визначилися)

Тому тут доведеться вдовольнитися окремим досвідом кожної людини:

"З повагою" – прекрасний варіант для будь-якого стилю, поважати можна як офіційно, так і неофіційно.

"На все добре" деяким людям може здатися більше фамільярністю, аніж неофіційним закінченням листа.

Якщо знаєте, що людина вашого листа прочитає прямо зараз, можна писати:
"Гарного дня", "Доброго вечора", "Доброї ночі".

Якщо в листі обговорюєте майбутню зустріч: "До побачення".

Якщо питаєте щось і хочете отримати відповідь якнайскоріше: "Наперед дякую за відповідь".

Comment: Щодо "Наперед дякую...", то це навіть якось без поваги (знаю, що зробиш, адже не куди не подінешся)
Ось що кажуть стосовно аналогічного підпису в англійській ["Thank you in advance"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/666/thank-you-in-advance-how-to-replace)

Comment: @bv., йой, як давно я писав те запитання №666 :)

Answer (score 2):

Колись працював у технічній підтримці одного міжнародного банку, мова спілкування була англійською, проте підпис розбавляв хто як хотів : була й польська, й португальська.

Я ж додав після "класичного" 'Best regards' ще й "З повагою та найкращими побажаннями". В принципі, достатньо було й просто "З повагою".

Що цікаво: на одного такого листа (з Литви, здається) у відповіді після "Oh, yes, thanks, the problem is solved" йшло "Велике спасибі".

Тому вважаю варіант "З повагою" доволі актуальним та нейтральним. А ось "наперед дякую" здебільшого у листуваннях радять уникати, адже це позаочі змушує людину щось робити. Не те, що це дуже погано, проте виглядає як "ну і коли ти будеш робити те, що я тобі сказав?"